# Excel add hours to date excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: excel, workday-api

I would like to add hours on a start date and skip weekends and holidays in an Excel file.

The hours would be 24, 36 and 48.

So if the start date and time are 4 Mar 2019, 13:42, the end date and time should be  :

- 24 hours: 5 Mar 2019, 13:42
- 36 hours: 6 Mar 2019, 01:42
- 48 hours: 6 Mar, 2019, 13:42

I am now using this formula:

```
=WORKDAY(E2,G2/24,Holidays!$A$2:$A$18)+MOD(E2,1)
```

E2 is the start date and time in mm/dd/yy hh:mm format, G2 is the number of hours, Holidays!$A$2:$A$18 is the range of holiday.

This formula works totally fine for 24 hours and 48 hours, however, it is not working for 36 hours. It would be much appreciated if someone would help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a simple date from addition and then convert it to the workday.

```
=WORKDAY(A2+B2/24-1, 1, Holidays!$A$2:$A$18)+MOD(A2+B2/24, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful with the response you marked as the accepted answer. Adding the times to the end after achieving the workday could push a Friday into Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, that i use for shift planning - LET is used only in excel 365, but i use it only for readability sake

```
=LET(days, (A3 / (A2 * 8)),
     decimal_start, (A1 - ROUNDDOWN(A1, 0)),
     decimal_end, (days - ROUNDDOWN(days, 0)),
     IF(decimal_start+decimal_end>1,
        WORKDAY(A1, days+1) +(decimal_start + decimal_end-1),
        WORKDAY(A1, days) + decimal_start + decimal_end
        )
    )
```

Where

- A1 is start day
- A2 is amount of shifts
- A3 is amount of hours to be added
- List item

So we simply calculate how much working days our hours contain, add them using WORKDAY function, and then manually adding the decimals (hours) from the original date, and from end date
additional check if sum of start and end decimals bigger than one prevent the cases, where the formula falsely push our date into weekend